# How add parent inside using genealogy tree?

Tags: tikz-pgf, genealogytree

I am building the genealogy tree of my family (all of them even the distant). I would like to add my great-great-grandmother, of the branch of my great-grandmother. The branch of my great-grandfather there are not problem.
This is a part (branch grandmother), by way of example:

```
\documentclass[a4,10pt,landscape]{article}
\usepackage{incgraph}
\usepackage[all]{genealogytree}

\newcommand{\f}{female}
\newcommand{\m}{male}

\gtrset{database format=short,edges={anchoring=center},language=spanish, level 0/.style={level distance=5mm}, level -1/.style={level distance=10mm},level -2/.style={level distance=15mm,level size=20mm, node size = 20mm},timeflow=down}
\gtrset{comment code={(\gtrDBcomment)}}

\begin{document}
\begin{inctext}
\begin{genealogypicture}[processing=database,database format=full,template=signpost,node size=3cm,level size=3.2cm,list separators hang,place text={\newline}{},box={fit basedim=9pt,boxsep=2pt,segmentation style={solid},halign=left,before upper=\parskip1pt,\gtrDBsex}]
sandclock
{
    child{
        g[\m]{
            my great-great-grandfatherX
        }
        p[\f]{
            my great-great-grandmotherX
        }
        child{
            g[\m]{
                my great-grandfatherX
            }
            p[\f,processing=database]{
                name={my great-grandmotherY},
                comment={\textbf{Here!} How add her mother or father?},
            }
            child{
                g[\f]{my grandmotherX}
                p[\m]{my grandfatherZ}
                c[\f]{my aunt}
                c[\m]{my other uncle}
                child{
                    g[\f]{my other aunt}
                    p[\m]{husband of my aunt}
                    c[\f]{my cousin}
                }
                child{
                    g[\m]{my father}
                    p[\f]{my mother}
                    c[\f]{my sister}
                    c[\m]{my brother}
                    c[\m]{me}
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
\end{genealogypicture}
\end{inctext}

\end{document}
```

I tried using parent inside this:

```
   p[\f,processing=database]{
            name={my great-grandmotherY},
            comment={\textbf{Here!} How add her mother or father?},
            parent{
                    g[\f]{my great-great-grandmotherY}
            },
    }
```

not work but at least did not show error. It is almost similar to example from genealogytree's manual for Gauss's genealogy tree (page 39 to 42), but I do not work correctly.
[image]

Thanks a lot!
Darío

Comment: use `parents` instead of `parent`.

Comment: Hello, how would it be like? Because I can not find the parents command in the genealogytree's package?